# Maya 2020 How to connect joints to an animated alembic mesh

Tags: maya, alembic

I'm trying to create joints on top of an animated Alembic mesh in order to use them later as a skin deformer.The current issue is that the joints are following the geometry.

Do I need to create a proper character rig for that? Is there a simple way to connect them directly to the original geometry without to have the package "duplicated geometry/blendshape/follicle"?

Many thanks,

Comment: SO is a coding community, your question does not really fit in here, try the Autodesk Area forums instead.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for answering. OK sure ! The idea behind this was to get some suggestions and the best way how to handle that before to automate it by a Python script. I guess I will open a new post with a related code... Cheers